# VBA to extraxt text from string

Tags: excel, vba, string

I have a dataset in excel which looks like this:

[image]

There can be more cells with data. I am trying to extract data from these big cells and paste values to more comprehensive table, which should look like this:

[image]

What would be the best way to proceed? I imagine process should look like this:
Select range of filled cells, store row count as value
Do a loop for that many rows as value
Store whole cell value as string
Find "Btc = *" and store it as btc value. Paste that value into prefered table
Find "Qua= *" and store it as qua value. Paste that value into prefered table
..etc
Clean up cells in new table using Replace

I am stuck on extracting part of text to value. What function can I use to assign that "Btc = *" to variable? Like operator gets be a whole string, but I only need parts of it
Or maybe you have ideas on how to do this task easier?

Comment: I can see there are issues which repeats. How to proceed in such cases? I mean Dia, Thk, Sor etc. Then, are they only doubled, as you can see, or  can there be more of them?

Comment: In this case, values from one cell should go to one row of new table. Same values are allowed

Comment: If you are using VBA, for all of the values I can see in your data table, you can extract the 'value' from the string as follows... If `str = "Btc = 22C2002055"` then `Mid(str, InStr(1, str, " = ") + 3)` extracts `22C2002055` which is what I assume you want. This is also possible using Excel formulas, of course, you'd just need to use the worksheet functions analogous to the demonstrated VBA functions. If you are sure that the `tag` is always 3 letters (e.g. `Btc`, `Dia`, `Thk`, ...), like in your example table, you could also just use `Mid(str, 7)` to extract the value.

Comment: OK,. Now, you you have another sheet with the appropriate headers, or you need the code to also extract them from the column? Then, you did not answer if there can be much more such sequences then the ones shown in your picture... According to this aspect the code can be designed differently (using arrays in case of a huge range)...

Comment: The problem that all values may change, so I can't just put if "Btc = 22C2002055". So if that value changes, I will not be able to extract it. I need to figure out how to get that value even if it's shorter, longer, or it will contain letters only

Comment: First picture depicts exact data as I get to excel. That sheet may contain any number of rows, I just showed picture of two, but it can be up to 100 or so. Second sheet has table with headers like in the second picture, which are set. Their order may change if that makes anything easier

Comment: If they can change, how to make anything easier? What do you mean by "Their order may change"? Will they be on headers row in the order they are on the A:A column, or in different positions? Are there **a table** where the values must be placed? When you say "table"do you mean a `listObject`, or a simple range? Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @FaneDuru by changing order I meant that table headers in second picture are not in the order like they are in cells in first picture. If that somehow that makes things more difficult, and it is better to order headings like they are in the cell, it is doable

Comment: There is a table in second sheet where values from these cells in the first picture must be placed. I mean simple range

Comment: Then, if a simple range, the header can be build **as the existing order in column A:A**. Is it also possible that the order in A:A to  not be the same for all sequences of 10 rows?

Comment: No, once one sequence is done, order should remain the same for the rest

Comment: OK. I will prepare an answer.

Comment: Please, test the code in my answer and send some feedback. Take care to adapt the code for the destination sheet, if you do not it returning in the next sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It uses arrays and will be very fast (working mostly in memory). Please adapt your real sheet used as destination, where the processed result to be dropped (`shDest`). Now, the code returns **in the next sheet**. If you want it as it is, please insert/have an empty sheet after the one to be processed:

```
Sub extractValTranspose()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, shDest As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin
  Dim i As Long, k As Long, j As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet to be processed
  Set shDest = sh.Next 'use here the sheet where you want the processed result to be dropped
  
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row in A:A
  arr = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR).Value2               'place the range in an array for faster iteration/procesing
  ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr) / 10 + 1, 1 To 10)    'redim the final array (to keep the processed data)
  
  'extract headers array:
  For i = 1 To 10
    arrFin(1, i) = Split(Replace(arr(i, 1), " ", ""), "=")(0) 'place the header on the first array row
    arrFin(2, i) = Split(Replace(arr(i, 1), " ", ""), "=")(1) 'place the data on the second row
  Next i
  
  k = 3: j = 1 'initialize variables keeping the (next) row and columns
  'place the rest of rows data:
  For i = 11 To UBound(arr)
    arrFin(k, j) = Split(Replace(arr(i, 1), " ", ""), "=")(1): j = j + 1
    If j = 11 Then k = k + 1: j = 1 'reinitialize the variable for each 10 rows
  Next
  
  'drop the array content, at once and do a little formatting:
  With shDest.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2))
    .Value2 = arrFin
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Borders.Color = vbBlack
    .BorderAround 1, xlMedium
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .BorderAround 1, xlMedium
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
     End With
  End With
  
  MsgBox "Ready..."
  shDest.Activate
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

Nothing from your question made me understand that **all groups of 10 strings to be processed are in the same cell**...

Please, test the next piece of code able to process the above mentioned range type:

```
Sub extractValSameCellTranspose()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, shDest As Worksheet, lastR As Long
  Dim arr, arrCell, arrFin, i As Long, k As Long, j As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet to be processed
  Set shDest = sh.Next 'use here the sheet where you want the processed result to be dropped
  
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in A:A
  arr = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR).Value2         'place the range in an array for faster iteration/procesing
  ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 10)     'redim the final array (to keep the processed data)
  
  'extract headers and first row of data:
    arrCell = Split(arr(1, 1), vbLf) 'split the cell content on vbLf (end of line)
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrCell)  'iterate between the above array elements
        arrFin(1, i + 1) = Split(VBA.replace(arrCell(i), " ", ""), "=")(0) 'place the header on the first array row
        arrFin(2, i + 1) = Split(VBA.replace(arrCell(i), " ", ""), "=")(1) 'place the data on the second row
   Next i
  
  k = 3 'initialize variable keeping the array rows
  'place the rest of rows data:
  For i = 3 To UBound(arr)
        arrCell = Split(arr(i, 1), vbLf)
        For j = 0 To UBound(arrCell)
            arrFin(k, j + 1) = Split(VBA.replace(arrCell(j), " ", ""), "=")(1)
        Next j
        k = k + 1
  Next
  
  'drop the array content, at once and do a little formatting:
  With shDest.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2))
    .Value2 = arrFin                          'drop the array content
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit               'autofit all columns
    .Borders.Color = vbBlack         'place some thin borders on each cell
    .BorderAround 1, xlMedium     'place a thicker border arround the whole range
    With .rows(1)                              'format the first (headers) row:
        .Font.Bold = True                           'make the font bold
        .BorderAround 1, xlMedium         'place a thicker border arround
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter 'center the string horizontaly
     End With
  End With
  
  MsgBox "Ready..."
  shDest.Activate 'activate the sheet where the processed result has been dropped
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: @Lukas Nickus Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it return what you need?

Comment: Thank you, did not have a time to test it yest. Will get back with results tomorrow

Comment: I tested it. Now it's your turn...

Comment: I get subscript out of range at 'arrFin(1, i) = Split(Replace(arr(i, 1), " ", ""), "=")(0) 'place the header on the first array row'

Comment: @Lukas Nickus Does your A:A column start from the second row, as in your picture? If not, insert a row above the range and test again. Are there empty cells in  A:A column? When stopped on error and moving the cursor over `arr(i,1)` what does it display? Is there any value?

Comment: Yes, data start from the second row, first one is just a heading called DATA, there are no empty cells between data, firs empty cell is after data ends at A10 for now.  There is  o value displayed in  arr (i, 1) it just says " arr(i, 1) = <subscript out of range>" "and i=10"

Comment: @Lukas Nickus I tested the code on data you show and some more and it worked as it should. I cannot imagine what's wrong on your file. Please, try using it on the dara you show in the picture. All of it, or with more 10 rows sequences. Do you have TeamViewer or AnyDesk installed? If so, and you accept a connection I would like to see what's happening in your workbook...

Comment: Our network does not allow remote connection like teamviewer. Anyway, thanks for your help, I will try to debug it myself for now since your code and comments are quite clear

Comment: @Lukas Nickus When code stopped on error please go up and move the cursor over `UBound(arr)`. What does it show? Is it 10?

Comment: @Lukas Nickus Just curious... Since the code works as it should in my installation, I would like to know what was wrong in our case.

Comment: UBound(arr) shows 10
by filling cells to A11, script stops at different place now arrFin(k, j), which is also subscript out of range

sorry for my English, it is hard to explain in not a native language

Comment: @Lukas Nickus I cannot get you... What did you change to pass the first error? What does  `UBound(arr)` shows now when stopped on error? What value do `i` and `j` have when stopped on error? Does moving the cursor over `arr(i, 1)` show anything? I mean, what value is in the respective cell (one row below `i`). Does it have a "=" character in it? The code needs consistent a range in terms of patterns. It can be handled, anyhow, but I need to know what's happening and because of what...

Comment: I will try to organize remote session with you, probably tomorrow, if you can give me a way to contact you privately

Comment: @Lukas Nickus If difficult, if your workbook is not confidential you can send it to me (on my personal mail in my profile). If conf, try creating a dummy workbook, **test it if the above code works/not work on it** and send it to me or a link here using a transfer site. I will try looking at it and see what problem you may have... Even if, seeing it on your computer will be more helpful, especially for you, to better understand how such situations can be degugged.

Comment: @Lukas Nickus Didn't you find some  time to share somehow a relevant workbook?

Comment: @Lukas Nickus Please, test the code I placed after "**Edited**:" and send some feedback.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly as needed now

Answer (score 1):

### Transform Data With Split

```vb
Sub TransformData()

    ' Define constants.

    Const SRC_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_COLUMN As Long = 1
    Const SRC_ROW_DELIMITER As String = vbLf ' vbCrLf?
    Const SRC_COL_DELIMITER As String = "="
    Const DST_NAME As String = "Sheet2"
    Const DST_FIRST_COLUMN As Long = 2
    Const OVERWRITE_MODE As Boolean = False
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Write the source data to an array, the source array ('sData').
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    
    Dim sData() As Variant, srCount As Long
    
    With sws.UsedRange
        srCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        If srCount = 0 Then
            MsgBox "No data in the source worksheet.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        With .Columns(SRC_COLUMN).Resize(srCount).Offset(1) ' source data range
            If srCount = 1 Then
                ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = .Value
            Else
                sData = .Value
            End If
        End With
    End With
    
    ' Write the destination header data to an array ('hData') and reference
    ' the first destination row range ('dfrrg').
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_NAME)
    Dim dfrrg As Range, hData() As Variant, dcCount As Long, dc As Long
    
    With dws.UsedRange
        Dim dcOffset As Long: dcOffset = DST_FIRST_COLUMN - 1
        dcCount = .Columns.Count - dcOffset
        With .Columns(1).Resize(, dcCount).Offset(, dcOffset) ' header range
            If OVERWRITE_MODE Then
                Set dfrrg = .Rows(1).Offset(1)
            Else
                Set dfrrg = .Rows(1).Offset(.Rows.Count)
            End If
            hData = .Value
        End With
    End With
    
    ' Write the destination header data to a dictionary.
    
    Dim hDict As Object: Set hDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    hDict.Comparemode = vbTextCompare
    
    For dc = 1 To dcCount: hDict(hData(1, dc)) = dc: Next dc
    
    If hDict.Count < dcCount Then
        MsgBox "No duplicates are allowed in the destination header row.", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Erase hData
    
    ' Define the destination array ('dData').
    ' Note that fewer rows are possible if blank or missing source values.
    
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To srCount, 1 To dcCount)
    
    ' Using the dictionary, write the matching values from the source array
    ' to the destination array.
    
    Dim sr As Long, sc As Long, sPos As Long, dr As Long, vLen As Long
    Dim sArr() As String, sString As String, sTitle As String, sValue As String
    Dim InNextRow As Boolean
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        sArr = Split(CStr(sData(sr, 1)), SRC_ROW_DELIMITER)
        For sc = 0 To UBound(sArr)
            sString = CStr(sArr(sc))
            sPos = InStr(sString, SRC_COL_DELIMITER)
            If sPos > 1 Then ' column delimiter it not the first character
                sTitle = Left(sString, sPos - 1)
                If hDict.Exists(sTitle) Then ' title found in the dictionary
                    vLen = Len(sString) - sPos
                    If vLen > 0 Then ' has a value
                        sValue = Right(sString, vLen)
                        If Not InNextRow Then dr = dr + 1: InNextRow = True
                        dData(dr, hDict(sTitle)) = sValue
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next sc
        If InNextRow Then InNextRow = False
    Next sr
    
    If dr = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No values found in the source worksheet.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Erase sData
    
    ' Write the values from the destination array to the destination range.
    
    dfrrg.Resize(dr).Value = dData ' 'dr', not 'srCount'
    If OVERWRITE_MODE Then ' clear below
        dfrrg.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - dfrrg.Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr).Clear
    End If
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Data transformed.", vbInformation

End Sub
```